# how to open port on apache server

Tags: apache-2.2

EDIT:
**I would like to open 8080 and 1337 ports on my computer, how can I do it?
how can I check that the apache server listen on 8080?**

---

For a laboratory work,  I am using apache2.2 server, I need to open port 8080 and 1337 on this server, I am told that I need to open it by changing httpd.config file in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\conf. I see that I can edit it by opening with notepad. Can anybody tell me what to edit in httpd.config to open these ports?

Comment: You **open** ports on the firewall. You make Apache **listen** on specific ports. Please clarify which you want.

Comment: @Johan, please don't take any further advise from the person who told you this.

Answer (score 2):

You want the "listen" directive.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#listen

Answer (score 2):

The `Listen` directive is what you need. You should have a file called `ports.conf` in your Apache folder (on Windows) or under `/etc/apache2/`. If you wanted to configure Apache to listen on ports 8080 and 1337, you'd add:

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:8080
Listen 0.0.0.0:1337
```

This would cause Apache to listen on all interfaces. If you just want Apache to listen on a single IP address, you'd add:

```
Listen 192.168.66.22:8080
Listen 192.168.66.22:1337
```

To verify Apache listens on that port, you could use a telnet session, like so (assuming 192.168.66.22 is the server's IP address):

```
telnet 192.168.66.22 8080
```

If you get some output, the server listens to that port.

Comment: About that telnet, you'd have to type an HTTP request to get any output. Like "GET / HTTP/1.0" + Enter + Enter. And on Windows telnet, you have to type that blind. And without any typo. You can simply point a browser to http://192.168.66.22:8080 instead.

Comment: Well. As soon as you get a prompt, telnet has successfully connected to the web server. He asked about how to test if a web server listens to that port, not if the web server serves something useful.

Answer (score 0):

In your apache basedir e.g. /etc/apache2 you'll find a ports.conf file. Edit it following the description here -> http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/

besides that you certainly have to add the port settings also to you virtual hosts in order to get them run behind this port...

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to Apache, I recommend using a tool to edit the httpd.conf, rather than messing with the file.

Here is one: http://www.apache-gui.com/apacheconf/index.html